# In R, why is passing ls as a function argument differ from passing ls() as a function argument?

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

```
f <- function(x) {
  a <- 1
  x
}
f(ls())
```

In the above code, the call to f(ls()) will print out the variables in the global environment.

But:

```
f <- function(x) {
  a <- 1
  x()
}
f(ls)
```

will print out the variables in the environment of the function f, namely "a" and "x".

Comment: Scope and lazy evaluation. When you do `f(ls())`, the `ls()` call is evaluated in the scope of where it was called, and then passed to `f` as a `character` vector. When you do `f(ls)`, you are passing a function that determines (when it is called) what to use for `envir=`; at that time, the calling environment is within `f`, not `globalenv()` (assuming global for the first example). Suggestions: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html and http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html#function-envs.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you pass the results of `ls()` - which is a vector of all objects in the environment. And your function just prints what was passed with `x`, namely - the results of `ls()`.

In the second case you pass a function and the function get's executed within the function body.

Basically you can think about the first version of your call as:

```
x <- ls()
f(x)
```

As an additional example: look at the difference between `print(ls())` and `print(ls)`.

Comment: But r function arguments are lazily evaluated, which means ls() is evaluated inside the function also.

Comment: Hm not 100% sure (so not editing the answer as of now) but I am pretty confident that lazy evaluation is done in the environment where the variable was defined. So when evaluating `x=ls()` R should see that it's environment was outside of this function and evaluate it there. If it worked the way you suspected - you would never be able to pass the results of `ls()` to any function.

Comment: @oahz The parameter is lazy evaluated, but when it is evaluated, it is evaluated in the calling environment. This is true for all parameters you pass into function (unless you capture the promise with non-standard evaluation). Otherwise you would never be able to pass in values from outside a function with variables.

Comment: There's at least one exception to @Ryan 's example: `f = function(x) {a <- 1; eval(substitute(x))}; f(ls())` (which is nonstandard evaluation as MrFlick describes)

Comment: @oahz misunderstands lazy evaluation. It controls when an argument is evaluated, not the context of the evaluation.

Comment: @MrFlick also gets it wrong in general, though not in this case.  Evaluation context is determined by the argument, not by when it is used.  For example, default values are evaluated in the current frame, not the calling environment.